# iOS: How to change UIImage with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uiimage

This might be simple, but I'm very new at developing an iOS APP. I have an UIButton and three UIImage's. What I'm trying to do is that when the user taps the button, the first image will display, if the user taps it again, then show the second image, and so on. When the last image is displaying, then go back to the first one when tapping the button again. The problem is that only the first image appears.

Here is my code:

file.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *images;

}

-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

file.m

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender{

images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Than you in advance!

Comment: What precisely do you think `image = [UIImage ...], [UIImage ...], [UIImage ...];` is supposed to do??

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a global variable for the index and global variable array to hold the image names

```
self.index = 0;
self.imageList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pic1", @"pic2", @"pic3", nil];
```

then in the click action, you can do

```
-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender{
    images.image = [UImage imageNamed:self.imageList[self.index]];
    self.index = (self.index + 1 ) % [self.imageList count];
}
```

I don't have the compiler with me to verify the syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: I would also recommend picking up a book on iOS development. This will teach you some basics. Have you developed in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, create a counter called tapCounter in viewDidLoad. Let's imagine you already set your image array as follows in viewDidLoad. Make sure images and tapCounter are properties of your class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
self.images = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"]];


self.tapCounter = 0;
}


-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {

    UIButton *but = (UIButton *)sender;
    tapCounter++;

    if (tapCounter == 4) {
       tapCounter = 1;
    }

    [but setBackgroundImage:[images objectAtIndex:tapCounter-1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    }
```